# C++: Trouble with string indexing and keeping punctuation

Tags: c++, string, indexing

So i have a function that technically indexes the characters between the first and laster chars in the string, scrambles up the inside then adds the first and last letter back on.  It works fine until I realized words with punctuation makes it screwy.  I want the punctuation to stay in the same index, any ideas on how to go about doing so?

```
string shuffle_word(string word){
    string scramble_str = "", full_scramble = "";
    if(word.length() > 2){
        scramble_str += word.substr(1, word.length()-2);  //indexes the inside string (excludes first and last char)
        random_shuffle(scramble_str.begin(), scramble_str.end());
        full_scramble = word[0] + scramble_str + word[word.length()-1]; //adds first and last char back on
        return full_scramble;
    }
    else{
        return word;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "punctuation" you mean things like diacritical marks, accents, etc.? ... because words don't have punctuation but they do have diacritical marks. Further, there is a substantial difference between them: punctuation are characters themselves while diacritical marks are part of characters and potentially encoded using multiple bytes for just one character.

Comment: Yes punctuation as in a any of these ,.?!'";:

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to use a variation of the same thing you're doing with the first and last characters:

1. record the position of each punctuation character
2. extract and save the punctuation characters
3. scramble the letters
4. insert each punctuation character at its original location

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list of the indices of the non-punctuation characters, then shuffle the indices. Then reform the string like so:

```
    if (numShuffledIndices > 0)
    {
        char temp = word[shuffledIndices[0]]; // save first character
        for (int i = 0; i < numShuffledIndices-1; ++i)
        {
            word[shuffledIndices[i]] = word[shuffledIndices[i+1]];
        }
        word[shuffledIndices[numShuffledIndices-1]] = temp;
    }
```

So if the string was "Hello, world!", the indices would be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]. If they were shuffled to [7, 4, 2, 9, 1, 0, 11, 8, 3 10], the resulting string would be "dHrll, olewo!"

Answer (score 0):

I would go for something like this:

```
std::vector<int> punctuatuion_char_indicies = findIndiciesOfPunctuation(input_string);

std::string result = shuffle_word(input_string);


std::vector<int> punctuatuion_char_indicies2 = findIndiciesOfPunctuation(result);




for(int i=0; i< sizeOfPunctuationVectors ; ++i)
{
  std::swap( result[ punctuatuion_char_indicies[i] ], 
             result[ punctuatuion_char_indicies2[i] ); // std::swap is in <algorithm>
}
```

Or you can use punctuatuion_char_indicies vector to perform your shuffle function in parts.